# STM32CubeIDE - build from windows batch file

Tags: c, batch-file, stm32cubeide

I would like to be able to build project releases from a batch file rather than the GUI as in my opinion it makes the whole process more controlled.

I'm struggling to find examples of this online. Has anyone else done it?

Comment: Your question is off topic for this site, and offering a bonus to other account holders does not make it any less off topic. Please retake the site [tour], then spend a little time reading through and understanding the information linked within [ask].

Comment: I have done this using STM32CubeMX. Not sure how to do it using the ide. The IDE should run a build command somewhere you should just be able to copy the make or cmake command and run it.

Comment: @Compo Instead of saying what they did wrong you should tell them how to do it right, or send them somewhere appropriate to ask. Telling them they are wrong for asking isn't helpful or going to show them how to ask a question in the future.

Comment: @JesseTaube, I didn't just tell them they were wrong, I provided links to the site tour, and how to ask a question. Have you read those? or did you just feel like an argument? This site has guidelines, and asking for reference material/links showing code examples is not what we do here. There is a search facility at the top of each page of this site, for people to use to locate code examples they can use to begin to code their particular tasks. We are not here to perform their searches for them, then link the results, or to write code for them to order. "Has anyone done it" is not on topic.

Comment: @Compo Questions asking how to use a command-line linking with an otherwise graphical programming IDE are perfectly on-topic. The only off-topic part here is "where to find examples".

Comment: Their question is "Has anyone done it"? Which in the context of what was posted means, "Has anyone found online examples"? It is completely off topic as it currently stsnds.

Comment: @Compo Even if the question is off-topic, which it may be, the people of stack overflow should show people how to ask questions rather than tell them the question is wrong.

Comment: Absolute rubbish @JesseTaube, the site provides the guidelines, it's not my job to duplicate or reproduce them every time a questioner fails to have read or followed them. I provided a link, the least they, and yourself if needs be, can do is click on it, read it, and understand it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Im on Linux but it should be similar on Windows.

I went to my project right, clicked the project name in `Project Explorer`, hovered over `Show In`, and clicked `System Explorer`.

I then entered the directory `Release` which there should be a `Makefile`
on Linux, in the release directory, I run `make`.

`~/STM32CubeIDE/workspace_1.7.0/TEST/Release$ make`

This will generate a `.bin` file and an `.elf` file, which can be used to program the chip with `STM32CubeProgramer`.

Comment: In addition to my reply to your comment under the question itself, this is a programming code site, not a "how do I use a particular piece of GUI software" reference site.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to use the CLI version to be able to automatically flash a device without GUI.

```
STM32_Programmer_CLI -c port=usb1 -w my_flash_layout.tsv
```